# Don't split string if the desired character is inside quotation marks in java

Tags: java, string, split

Say if I want to split following strings by the character ","

see picture
[strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDgR2.png)

As you can see, there are 3 lines, in first line, substring

```
    "HALLIBURTON OIL WELL CEMENTING CO. v. WALKER et al., DOING BUSINESS AS DEPTHOGRAPH CO."
```

is inside quotation marks but there is also a "," included, which doesn't happen in following 2 lines.

I want to keep the substring inside quotation marks, in other words, "," inside quotation marks shouldn't be considered by String.split(","), how do I achieve it?

Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: DO NOT write your own CSV parser, use one of the existing high-quality debugged open-source parsers available, such as OpenCSV or Apache Commons CSV.

Comment: In this case I only need to handle this special case, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can't possibly KNOW that's the only special case you'll have to handle.  You'll have to convince us that it really IS the only possibility, and then we'd have to ask what is the point of a system that handles only one piece of data, known beforehand.

Comment: show your full input case

Comment: Because I'm processing a fairly small csv file.

Comment: How are you planning to handle nested quotation marks? You see... Stick with the existing.

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, simply do

```
    str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

Not sure if it satisfy the requirement, any comments?